# Call original signal handler from custom signal handler

Tags: c, linux, signals

Subject says it all.

I want to be able to defer to the default OS signal handler for certain signals after I am done with my cleanups.

E.g. if SIGINT is received I want to terminate the program after my custom cleanup routine and want to make use of the standard OS routine for that instead of callind _exit() or whatever.

I figure I can get a reference to the original signal handler somehow before overwriting it with sigaction(), but i don't know how to do that.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigterm_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sighup_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sig_default_flag = 0;

void sigact(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucontext)
{
    switch(signum)
    {
    case SIGTERM:
        sigterm_flag = 1;
        break;
    case SIGHUP:
        sighup_flag = 1;
        break;
    default:
        sig_default_flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_sigaction = sigact;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    while (1) {
        if (sigterm_flag == 1) {
            sigterm_flag = 0;
            printf("SIGTERM caught.\n");
        }
        if (sighup_flag == 1) {
            sighup_flag = 0;
            printf("SIGHUP caught.\n");
        }
        if (sig_default_flag == 1) {
            sig_default_flag = 0;
            printf("Other signal caught.\n");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Challenge solved based on suggestion from [tuxlike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14466969/tuxlike) in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595945/8359654

Here is the final code:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sigterm_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sighup_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sig_default_flag = 0;

void sigact(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucontext)
{
    switch(signum)
    {
    case SIGTERM:
        sigterm_flag = 1;
        break;
    case SIGHUP:
        sighup_flag = 1;
        break;
    case SIGINT:
        sigint_flag = 1;
        break;
    default:
        sig_default_flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct sigaction sa_default;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = sigact;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigemptyset(&sa_default.sa_mask);
    sa_default.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    sa_default.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    printf("Started %s as PID %ld\n", argv[0], (long int)getpid());

    while (1) {
        if (sigterm_flag == 1) {
            sigterm_flag = 0;
            printf("SIGTERM caught.\n");
        }
        if (sighup_flag == 1) {
            sighup_flag = 0;
            printf("SIGHUP caught.\n");
        }
        if (sigint_flag == 1) {
            sigint_flag = 0;
            printf("\nSIGINT caught.\n");
            sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_default, NULL);
            raise(SIGINT);
        }
        if (sig_default_flag == 1) {
            sig_default_flag = 0;
            printf("Other signal caught.\n");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tuxlike answer is correct, I deleted mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that you are missing [`sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetops.3.html) from your signal action structure initialization.  It is a common, recommended practice to initially do a `memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);` to initialize all, even padding, to all-zeros, first.)

There is no userspace function for the default signal handler actions at all, the default handling happens in the kernel.

What you can do, is use [`sigaction()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to reset the default action (`sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL; sa.sa_flags = 0;`), then re-raise the signal using [`raise(signum)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html), and return from the handler.

Both `sigaction()` and `raise()` are [async-signal safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), and therefore perfectly acceptable to use in a signal handler.